# Docker attach delay

Tags: docker

I have a docker container running an Python script each 1 minute. The script returns a timestamp and true or false depending on the result of the operation.

The log of my script is:

```
2015-11-03 16:41:44.509863 (true)
2015-11-03 16:42:44.511375 (true)
2015-11-03 16:43:44.531248 (true)
2015-11-03 16:44:44.531558 (false)
```

If I run my container using -it I see the results as expected. 
But once I run it with -d and access the container using attach I receive a batch of results from time to time.

I know my script is running OK as the timestamp is correct, the point is that after 5~10 minutes I receive 5~10 logs at once on the terminal.

Any idea on what can be the problem here?

**Update**

I have also tried to use the "attach" command in a standard mongo image and I have the same results. Almost 5 minutes to get each mongo client result on my terminal, but if I connect to Mongo from the Mongo Client in my machine the result is real time, so is not the container performance, but some kind of buffer/delay using the attach command.

**Update2**

A friend of mine in a similar environment (OS X 10.11 and Docker 1.9) did a few tests using "docker attach" and has the same results as mines. A very long delay to get the results displayed on terminal.

Comment: Sounds like the logs are being buffered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research I still could not found a solution or explanation for the behaviour of the attach command, but I finally can attach to the containers and perform any action safely using the exec command:

```
docker exec -it {{containerNameOrId}} bash
```

Just run it with your container name or id and you are able to access the container bash and perform any action.